# how to get checkbox event from grid?

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, kendo-ui

[image: Kendo Grid]

how i can get sum of balance amount of checked row?

I am not able to get event of checkbox and then column's value of that particular row.
Please help me out.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have already done.

Comment: i had used checkbox column as template in kendo grid, so i am not able to gets its value

Answer (score 1):

I got my Ans by my own

```
var grid = $("#amount_detail").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.tbody.on("change", ".ob-paid", function (e) {
              var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
              var item = grid.dataItem(row);
              var balance_amount = item.balance_amount;
              item.set("checkbox", $(e.target).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0);

              if($(e.target).is(":checked")==1){  
                      var t = ($("#tot_balance").val() * 1)+(balance_amount * 1);  
                      $("#tot_balance").val(t);  
              }
              else{
                  var t = ($("#tot_balance").val() * 1)-(balance_amount * 1);
                  $("#tot_balance").val(t);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a prototype on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kukagome/1/edit) for you to check out. This should contain all of the necessary components to do what you're asking for. I am assuming the Kendo UI grid has an ID, so you would want to replace the selector that I have used with your grid's ID. However, the concept is essentially what you're looking for.

Assuming you have a grid with the id myTable, you would be able to do something like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Select
            </th>
            <th>
               Action
            </th>
            <th>
               Action
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Unique ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Format
            </th>
            <th>
                Job #
            </th>
            <th>
                Total Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Balance Amount
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Make Payment" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Change Details" />
            </td>
            <td>
                John Doe
            </td>
            <td>
                12345
            </td>
            <td>
                AIR CAN
            </td>
            <td>
                Random Number 11122
            </td>
            <td>
                1500
            </td>
            <td class="balance">
                2340
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Make Payment" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Change Details" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Jane Doe
            </td>
            <td>
                56789
            </td>
            <td>
                LCL CAN
            </td>
            <td>
                Random Number 14562
            </td>
            <td>
                1300
            </td>
            <td class="balance">
                1000
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Make Payment" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Change Details" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Jim Bob
            </td>
            <td>
                82352
            </td>
            <td>
                AIR CAN
            </td>
            <td>
                Random Number 985613
            </td>
            <td>
                600
            </td>
            <td class="balance">
                800
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<p id="total">
</p>
```

You're JavaScript might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Store the totals here.
    var totals = [];
    //Handle checkbox click.
    $('#myTable input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
        var sum = 0;//For adding the sum
        //Get the cell with the balance in it.
        var number = $(this).parentsUntil('tbody').find('.balance').text();
        //Handle if checked
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).parentsUntil('tbody').addClass('highlight');
            totals.push(parseInt(number));
        }else{//Handle if not checked
            $(this).parentsUntil('tbody').removeClass('highlight');
            var idx = totals.indexOf(parseInt(number));
            totals.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        for (var n = 0; n < totals.length; n++){
            sum += totals[n];
        }
        $('#total').text(sum > 0 ? sum : "");
    });
});
```

Please see the prototype for clarification on use and for a live demo of the code.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your ans but its too advanced code for me. i didn't understand it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you don't understand it. :(